# rewriteCond match a URL segment and check if it's a directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this `server.com/foo/bar/abc`

I want to see if the first segment of the URL is a directory. I have this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9_]+)/(.*)
RewriteCond $1 -d # <- this does not work
RewriteRule . %1/index.html [L]
```

Lines 1 and 3 work fine. I'm able to match `%1` with the first segment. But line 2 does nothing. 
I also tried `%1` on line 2 and the result is the same. The entire rule fails because line is false. How can I match if previous matched pattern is a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: The last RewriteRule gives a recursion but I think you helped me solve it by adding the DOCUMENT_ROOT. That was the part I was missing

Comment: You can try adding the condition `RewriteCond $2 !index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it to work like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9_]+)/?(.*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ app/index.html [L]
```